# Advanced conditionals: {if field1:total_rows == 0 && field2:total_rows == 0} always return TRUE

Tags: matrix

I have tried many different variations:

{if field1:total_rows == 0 && field2:total_rows == 0} No rows {/if}

{if field1:total_rows == 0 AND field2:total_rows == 0} No rows {/if}

{if {field1:total_rows} == 0 && {field2:total_rows} == 0} No rows {/if}

{if "{field1:total_rows}" == 0 AND "{field2:total_rows}" == 0} No rows {/if}

They all evaluates TRUE, even though field1 and field2 have matrix rows in the entry.

I finally had to do something like this:
{if field1:total_rows == 0}{field2:total_rows == 0} No rows {/if}{/if}

How do I construct the conditionals without nesting two {if}?

We are on EE 2.9, Matrix 2.6

Comment: What do you get if you try to output {field1:total_rows} etc? Are your conditionals nested inside a matrix tag pair?

Comment: @foamcow When field1 has no rows, {field1:total_rows} output blank instead of zero.  Should my conditional be testing for '' (empty string) instead of 0?  The conditionals are not nested inside a matrix tag, it is nested within {exp:channel:entries) tag.

Comment: @foamcow The original code is: <li class="{if field1:total_rows == 0 AND field2:total_rows == 0}without-thumb{/if}">

Comment: @foamcow -- I just tried <li class="{if field1:total_rows == '' AND field2:total_rows == ''}without-thumb{/if}">, and without-thumb doesn't output even though field1 and field2 has no rows.

Comment: @foamcow -- I finally get it to behave correctly by adding "{}" around field1 and field2.  <li class="{if "{field1:total_rows}" == '' AND "{field2:total_rows}" == ''}without-thumb{/if}"> where without-thumb will only be outputted if both field1 and field2 has no rows. However, it seems inconsistent to test for values returned by total_rows (i.e. field1:total_rows == 1), and I am reluctant to test total_rows this way.  Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: I think this is a repercussion of the changes to conditionals in EE 2.9. I can't even get a simple `{if matrix_field:total_rows}Has Rows{/if}` conditional to work as expected. I have to force the parsing of the `matrix_field:total_rows` off to Matrix to get the results I expect by wrapping it in quotation marks so EE evaluates it as a string, have curly brackets inside those so EE passes the parsing over to Matrix, and then compare it to 0: `{if '{matrix_field:total_rows}' > 0}Has Rows{/if}`.